Noisy expectation value of non-Pauli observable in qiskit
I would like to calculate an expectation value of a general operator in a noisy simulation with qiskit.
The usual way of doing this is via an Estimatorwith a noise model. However, the run()function of the Estimator usually takes sequences of strings describing Pauli words and does not accept a list of Operator objects as input for the observable. The observable I want to calculate the expectation value of is a general operator (to be precise a density matrix as I am looking to calculate a fidelity).
Another way of calculating an expectation value with qiskit is either via StateFN.eval()or Statevector.expectation_value(). But both obviously don't allow for noisy simulations.
Can I somehow obtain the density matrix after the noisy simulation and calculate the expectation value via DensityMatrix.expectation_value()?
It feels like I am missing something obvious.
I read that a general operator internally is translated to a SparsePauliOp. But simply changing the class does not work. Why is this?

The SparsePauliOp class has a from_operator method that you can use to convert your observable into something you can pass to the Estimator. Is that what you are looking for? It might be easier if you share some sample code of what you are trying to accomplish.

Yes, that is exactly what I was looking for! As I already assumed, I missed something obvious. Should I delete this question, since it is kind of stupid?

No, because it might later help someone having the same question! However, if you don't mind @diemilio you should probably post an answer

Sounds good. Done.

The SparsePauliOp class has a from_operator() method that you can use to convert your observable into something you can pass to the Estimator. Here's a simple example:
# Imports
from math import pi
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile
from qiskit.quantum_info import SparsePauliOp, Operator
from qiskit_aer import AerSimulator
from qiskit_ibm_runtime import EstimatorV2

# Create estimator object
backend = AerSimulator()
estimator = EstimatorV2(mode=backend)

# Define operator
O = Operator([[1,0,0,-2j],
              [0,0,0,0],
              [0,0,0,0],
              [2j,0,0,1]])

# Convert to Pauli Word
obs = SparsePauliOp.from_operator(O)

# create quantum circuit
qc = QuantumCircuit(2)
qc.rx(pi/3,1)
qc.cx(1,0)

# transpile
qc_t = transpile(qc,backend)

#run simulation
job = estimator.run([(qc_t,[obs])])

exp_vals = job.result()[0].data.evs
print(exp_vals)

